# Filter the subject and message for email sent to the customer when they reset their password in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, passwords, hook

After long searches I can not find a hook to filter the subject and the message for email sent to the customer when they reset their password in WooCommerce. **Is there one for that?**

I need to remove (or replace) the site title from the default `Password Reset Request for {site_title}` subject, the same for the message, without touching the templates.

I found the [WC_Email_Customer_Reset_Password](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-emails-class-wc-email-customer-reset-password.html) class, but I don't see a filter there.

Comment: Well first of all you have the email template itself, which you could overwrite.. further you can see that `WC_Email_Customer_Reset_Password` extends `WC_Email` so you can use the [`woocommerce_email_subject_(id)`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php#L381) hook. (Where ID = customer_reset_password) (Similar hooks can be found in the same file on lines 372 and 390)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @7uc1f3r I figured out how to solve my problem. For the email subject I used the `woocommerce_email_subject_customer_reset_password` filter and for the email content the `woocommerce_mail_content` filter, both you can find [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php#L381) and [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php#L652).

```
/** Filter the subject of reset password email notification **/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_customer_reset_password', function( $subject ) {
    // woocommerce_mail_content will fire only on customer password reset
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_mail_content', 'wc_retrieve_password_message' );
    $subject = 'Password Reset Request';
    return $subject;
} );

/** Filter the content of reset password email notification **/
function wc_retrieve_password_message( $message ) {
    $blogname = get_option( 'blogname' );
    if( str_contains( $message, $blogname ) ) {
        $message = str_replace( $blogname, home_url(), $message );
    }

    return $message;
}
```